# they are a traitor or they are traitors?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular-they

Which one is correct :  they are a traitor  or  they are  traitors ?

I read "they are a traitor" on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/southafrica/comments/5n5jrc/do_white_people_enjoy_living_in_south_africa/)

> According to some people on this Subreddit and in South Africa if a White South African leaves **they are a traitor**, racist and trying to destroy the country.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/18494/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting twist to the language.

The poster wanted to not have to write *he/she is a traitor*, changed he/she to they, and then had to use are.

It is considered acceptable in this context.

The issue is related to gender neutrality.

Please have a look at the gender neutral pronoun [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Singular_they):

> Since at least the 14th century, they (including derivatives and inflected forms, such as them, their, theirs, themselves, and themself) has been used, with varying degrees of general acceptance, to refer to a singular antecedent. This usage is often called the singular they. Today, it is unexceptional and often not regarded as incorrect, especially in informal language.<sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Singular_they)</sub>

Comment: This is a good answer, but you may want to explicitly answer the question, i.e. "They are a traitor" is correct in this context... I know you imply that in your second sentence, but we need to remember that the folks reading our answers may not be fluent in English. It helps to state things clearly.

Comment: @ColleenV: Nicely put. But at least mplungjan did actually post an answer here, and it *does* (explicitly or implicitly) contain all the relevant info. To be honest, if this answer hadn't already been posted when I first looked at the question, I might well have simply closevoted as a duplicate of an earlier "singular they" question (and I'm sure I'd have had no trouble finding one! :)

Comment: I did not actually know there were duplicates until I saw the link since I had not seen a Singular They mentioned by words

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did look for a duplicate when I added the singular-they tag and the closest I found (that was tagged - who knows there may be one out there tagged "grammar") was the related question I added in a comment.

Comment: I just like "Interesting twist to the language" as an introduction to this *specific* aspect of "singular they" usage. It's only when I really stop to think about it that I realise some nns must find it a bit baffling that we can say *If **someone doesn't** like it **they** are ungrateful* or *If **some people don't** like it **they** are ungrateful*. The only other thing it might be worth adding here is to point out that we ***can't*** say *If **John doesn't** like it **they** are ungrateful*.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the introduction before I realised there was an actual name for it. I understood the concept fully, hence the _The poster wanted to not have to write he/she is a traitor, changed he/she to they, and then had to use are._ and then I saw Colleen's link and realised it was an established concept

Comment: Now I've got to thinking even more, it seems to me *Your spouse can come if they want* is "okay", but not *Your wife can come if they want*. And I'm not sure how the former would play out in male-only context where it's assumed everyone in the audience is heterosexual.